# Тэг HTML <video>. Подскажите, как запускать видео при клике на область видео, а не в панели управления

Tags: html

```
<video width="880" height="496" poster="../pic/blockVideoBg.jpg">
                    <source src="video/video.mp4">
                </video>
```

Параметр controls не подходит. Нужно начинать/останавливать воспроизведение по клику на область самого видео.